# Python, Tried making a script which takes all directorys and renames all the files in them

Tags: python

I tried making an python script which gets all directorys then
goes to the directorys and changes all the files name to the directory name.

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\assets\steamcmd\yus.py", line 24, in <module>
    os.rename(OurFilePath, os.path.join(pathy, pathname+str(file_extension)))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku (cannot find file): 'steamapps\\workshop\\content\\573090\\2138774925\\.crash' -> 'steamapps\\workshop\\content\\573090\\2138774925\\2138774925
```

Code below which was used :

```
import os
directory = "steamapps\\workshop\\content\\573090\\"
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    files = os.listdir()
    pathy = os.path.join(directory, f)
    for index,file in enumerate(files):
       OurFilePath = os.path.join(pathy, file)
       filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(OurFilePath)
       pathname = os.path.basename(pathy)
       os.rename(OurFilePath, os.path.join(pathy, pathname+str(file_extension)))
```

Comment: `files = os.listdir()` This always returns the files in the _current_ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, i found the error and have fixed the code.

The problem was : I used os.listdir the wrong way.

Heres the fixed code which i used :

```
directory = "steamapps\\workshop\\content\\573090\\"
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    pathy = os.path.join(directory, f)
    for file in os.listdir(pathy):
       OurFilePath = os.path.join(pathy, file)
       filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(OurFilePath)
       pathname = os.path.basename(pathy)
       os.rename(os.path.join(os.path.join(directory, f), file), os.path.join(pathy, pathname+str(file_extension)))
```